# Do people with a lisp ever write in the same way they pronounce?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, speech

Just curious to know whether people who have a lisp (speech defect) ever write in the same way as they pronounce the word. For example, they pronounce ***s*** as /θ/ and ***z*** as /ð/. So, do they ever substitute "th" for "s" in writing, such as spelling the word *sick* as "thick"?

Comment: The fact that the commonest Spanish pronunciation of S is not the same as the English S does not mean 'Spanish is spoken with a lisp', any more than it means 'Americans can't pronounce S properly'.

Comment: Why on earth would a lisper spell words featuring an "s" differently? Who would even think that? Most times, lispers are not aware of their lisp. If they were, they would not lisp. They can be trained to be aware of their pronunciation and work on the "correct", non-lisp pronunciation. If they are not aware that they are lisping, why would anyone think that they would "thpell wordth the thame way that they are thpeaking?"

Comment: Many words are *pronounced differently* - but *spelt the same* - in the US & UK. Also some words are *spelt differently* in the two countries - but *pronounced the same*. This demonstrates that there is little connection between spelling and pronunciation.

Comment: Thometimeth, but it'th rare.

Comment: Different parts of the brain.  Some people who have suffered a stroke can't speak at all, but can still write perfectly well, and vice versa.  Speech and writing are processed in separate and distinct regions of the brain, and have little or nothing to do with each other.  Writing and reading are processed by the visual cortex, if I recall correctly, while speech (both generating and interpreting) are handled by specific parts of the auditory system, Broca's Area, and at least one or two other structures in the brain.

Comment: @Wad: I don't think "nothing" is correct. They may have "little" to do with each other, for whatever value of "little"; but there are various complicated conexions. @ all: This question is fine and in fact extremely interesting. The answer below, by someone who has actual experience, shows how a lisp may actually influence spelling occasionally, as it has been observed with many other accents or indiosyncratic variations in pronunciation. Anglo-Saxon linguistics nowadays seems to emphasise how separate speech is from writing; they are of course to some degree correct, but they exaggerate.

Answer (score 6):

No, they don't. Spelling is not entirely related to pronunication.

Just as people without a lisp have to work out the difference between *bough, cough, dough* and *tough*, people with a lisp know that the word they pronounce as *lithp* isn't spelled that way.

However: you are looking at this the wrong way.

A person with a lisp says that word [cruel irony!] /lɪθp/ but what they are actually saying is *lisp*. The fact that that sounds different to how others pronounce it doesn't change the way it's spelled. One might just as well ask about a word pronounced /treɪt̬ə/ but spelled *traitor* not *trader*.

Comment: Of course, some authors might attempt to convey a lisped utterance in a way the reader might readily grasp.

Comment: True. Oi moight attampt to wroite in a Sarssex arcsunt.

Comment: Rather like one of the most famous of all literary figures, who for a time had such a bad cold that his speeches at a banquet were 
limited to "Thag you very buch."

Comment: One minor correction. Spelling is not regularly related to pronunciation **at all** in Modern English. English spelling is Middle English spelling; that's why we can read Chaucer, with a little help, but if we heard it, we'd never understand what they were saying, because the sounds changed but the spelling didn't.

Comment: @John: While English spelling and pronunciation are less closely conexed than in many other languages (e.g. Turkish), still are various types of conexions exist. Sometimes one's particular accent or idiosyncratic pronunciation may shine through one's spelling; although this usually does not happen, it is not rare. It may be either deliberate or unintended. Dutch example: *mijn* is pronounced /mən/ bij most people, but /mə/ by certain people. It has been observed that the latter people make the typo *me* more often than most others. I myself occasionally typo *mijn* as *men*, but never as *me*.

Comment: See also the answer below.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: In light of the bad reception the question got, and its apparent impending closure, I decided to edit it to make it seem a bit less silly and obvious. However, this may invalidate your answer a bit (in the sense that the question in its previous form could be interpreted as "do people with a lisp write 'th' for 's' in general", while the new edits change it to ""do people with a lisp ever write 'th' for 's'"). I hope you'll forgive me.

Comment: @sumelic I don't think it invalidates the answer -- despite today's first downvote -- as the last paragraph is still valid. It's actually important: we **all** do that -- for example *cough* is said "coff" but no-one except an illiterate would actually spell it that way. Similarly a word a lisper might pronounce as "thor-wy" is still **spelled** *sorry.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach Have you read the other answer? What evidence do you have?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I used to have a fairly pronounced lisp up until mid teens and I do occasionally "lisp" when typing, particularly when tired or distracted.  For instance, I was just using instant messaging and asked a colleague "Is this the thought of thing you're looking for?"  (thought=sort).  It's particularly interesting that I wrote "thought" (making a valid word, but used in the wrong context) rather than "thort".  Note that this isn't due to any spell checker as the message wasn't spell checked.  I catch myself "lisp typing" like this rarely - maybe once or twice a year, and I *think* it has always resulted in a valid word (such as "thought" above) though I can't be sure.

Comment: Very interesting; I suspected that this might sometimes happen. Spelling and pronunciation are connected in convoluted and unpredictable ways.